# Can’t open images on visual studio

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

Hi I just start learning code I download visual studio and I’m following what is saying I the video, i create a folder called images to put the images but every time I try to drag the photo a message show, written  “ the file is not displayed in the text editor becuse it is either binary or uses an unsupported text enconding” every time  I try to open manually don’t even show the image on the folder,
And the image when I put on visual shows images.jfif I don’t know what is it, I can’t show pictures because say is to big

I try everything nothing work close the app restart computer nothing work

Comment: hey I think your image extension is not supported Try using another image with .jpg or .jpeg extensions or convert it using tools on the web